# Prototype of background save facility

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I have developed NoSQL database.

At the moment it has no threads (async).

When the database needs to save data to disk, it blocks connections until it saves.

This method works OK, because save is fast - 3-4 sec, but I still can improve by background save.

Here is the prototype of the background save facility.

I have the following questions:

1. Do I need `atomic`? I have only one thread, can I use just `thread::joinable()` instead?
2. Anything else I am missing?

### Option 1, use `atomic_bool` :

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


struct X{
    std::vector<int>    rw;
    std::vector<int>    ro;
    mutable
    std::atomic<bool>   saveInProgress{ false };
    std::thread     saveThread;

    ~X(){
        if (saveThread.joinable()){
            std::cout << "d-tor wait for join()" << '\n';
            saveThread.join();
        }

        std::cout << "d-tor save in foreground..." << '\n';

        if (!std::empty(rw)){
            using std::swap;
            swap(rw, ro);
            saveProcess_();
        }
    }

    // this is not multi threaded code
    void save(){
        if (saveInProgress){
            std::cout << "save wait for join()" << '\n';
            saveThread.join();
        }

        using std::swap;
        swap(rw, ro);

        saveInProgress = true;

        saveThread = std::thread{ [this](){ saveProcess_(); } };

        // this runs parallel with the thread now...
        rw.clear();
    }

private:
    void saveProcess_() const{
        std::cout << "Save process started " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';

        // saving vector...
        for(auto &x : ro){
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

            std::cout << "Save " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " " << x << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << "Save process done " << std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';

        saveInProgress = false;
    }

};

int main(){
    X x;

    x.rw = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };

    x.save();

    x.rw = { 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 };

    x.save();

    x.rw = { 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 };

    // d-tor will kick now...
}
```

## Option 2, no atomic, just `joinable()`:

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


struct X{
    using Container = std::vector<int>;

    Container       rw;
    Container       ro;
    std::thread     saveThread;

    ~X(){
        std::cout << "d-tor save in foreground..." << '\n';

        saveProcess__(rw);

        joinSaveProcess_("d-tor");
    }

    // this is not multi threaded code
    void save(){
        joinSaveProcess_("save");

        using std::swap;
        swap(rw, ro);

        saveThread = std::thread{ [this](){ saveProcess__(ro); } };

        // this runs parallel with the thread now...
        rw.clear();
    }

private:
    void joinSaveProcess_(const char *who){
        if (saveThread.joinable()){
            std::cout << who << " wait for join()" << '\n';
            saveThread.join();
        }
    }

    static void saveProcess__(Container const &data){
        auto id = std::this_thread::get_id();
        std::cout << "Save process started " << id << '\n';

        // saving vector...
        for(auto &x : data){
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);

            std::cout << " - " << id << " " << x << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << "Save process done " << id << '\n';
    }
};

int main(){
    if(1){
        X x;
        // d-tor will kick now...
    }

    std::cout << "------------------------------------" << '\n';

    if(1){
        X x;

        x.rw = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };

        // d-tor will kick now...
    }

    std::cout << "------------------------------------" << '\n';

    if(1){
        X x;

        x.rw = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };

        x.save();

        // d-tor will kick now...
    }

    std::cout << "------------------------------------" << '\n';

    if(1){
        X x;

        x.rw = { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 };

        x.save();

        x.rw = { 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29 };

        x.save();

        x.rw = { 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39 };

        // d-tor will kick now...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need atomic? I have only one thread, can I use just thread::joinable() instead?

If you only use an instance of `struct X` from one thread, then you could indeed use `thread::joinable()` to check whether the save thread is running. However, as soon as you have multiple threads accessing an `X`, then you need atomics, otherwise two threads can simultaneously check `thread::joinable()`, both get `false`, and then both will start a new `saveThread` simultaneously.

The atomic flag doesn't help you with thread safety in any way. It only ensures atomic modification of the flag itself.

> Anything else I am missing?

I can't tell, because you've just shown a prototype, and you haven't said what properties (like [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)) your database has. Most serious databases use some form of
a [transaction log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log), which is appended to for every operation on the database, they don't just rely on periodic saving of the data.